# .NET/C# Prometheus Metric gateway

Tags: c#, .net, prometheus, metrics

I'm using the prometheus nuget package [from nuget gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/prometheus-net/)
I have successfully setup a MetricServer at my backend-service

```
    var metricServer = new MetricServer(1234);
    metricServer.Start();
```

At my client application, I cannot start a metric-server due to firewall settings. Therefore, I want to push the metrics to the backend server. I successfully tested it with the [pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway), but I don't want to run an extra application at my backend-server.
Is it possible to send metrics to the MetricServer() from a client application?
Or is there possiblity to route a HttpRequestMessage from the client at the backend-service to the MetricServer?

Comment: Prometheus *pulls* data, it doesn't receive data from clients. `MetricServer` *is* the client application as far as Prometheus is concerned. It's the client endpoint that Prometheus will poll to retrieve metric values. It doesn't send data to Prometheus. If the application is down, the metrics are lost. That's why you need the push gateway - to cache metrics until Prometheus asks for them. It can also act as a proxy if the service and Prometheus can't talk to each other directly

Comment: Yes, I know that and the general workflow of prometheus. But is there a possibility to add metrics to a MetricServer() which are received by a HTTP request at the backend-service which hosts both, the HTTP handler where clients can send requests AND the MetricServer() where a prometheus instance can poll the metrics.

Comment: Isn't that what you *already* do? The problem is that Prometheus can't talk to your server at all. It doesn't matter what runs on the server if Prometheus can't talk to it. That's why you need a proxy on a different machine, that Prometheus can talk to. In [When to use the PushGateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/#alternative-strategies) the advice is against using PushGateway as a proxy though. Either put a Prometheus server in the same network or use [PushProx](https://github.com/prometheus-community/PushProx)

Comment: MetricsServer runs in the *client* applications and services to collect metrics. Whatever you call `client` and `backend service` are clients when it comes to Prometheus. So what do you mean by `client` and `backend service`? Where do they run? Aren't they on the same network?

Comment: I will take a look at PushProx.

Comment: Clients and backend are in the same network, but communication is limited by a firewall. Only Ports at the server are allowed to be accessed from the clients, not vice-versa. So, a Prometheus-instance cannot access any port at the client-machine.